# fgets() and weird characters in the end of the string, in C

Tags: c, string, fgets

I am trying to get a string from the standard input in C. So I tried to use the dumbest thing:

```
int main(){
      int j;
      char name[20];

   printf("Who are you? ");
   fgets(name,20,stdin);
   printf("Glad to meet you, %s",name);

      for(j=0;j<20;j=j+1){
          printf(" %d = %c\n  ", j, name[j]);
      }   
}
```

And all these strange characters appear:

```
    Who are you? Hana
Glad to meet you, Hana
   0 = H
   1 = a
   2 = n
   3 = a
   4 =

   5 =
   6 =  
   7 =  
   8 = Ŕ
   9 = ■
   10 = `
   11 =
   12 = Ý
   13 = o
   14 = 
   15 = v
   16 = P
   17 = 
   18 = @
   19 =
```

What is happening?

Comment: The array was not initialised - it's just junk - whatever happened to be in those memory locations. In C you must explictly initialise local (automatic) variables.

Comment: That's normal. You array can hold at most 20 chars, but it doesn't use them all. The valid part are the characters up to the first null character, `name[4]` in your case. The rest are unitilialized, but you usually don't care about them. (The 20 chars include the null char, so you name can be at most 19 characters long, `fgets` will ensure that.)

Comment: `printf` format `%c` does not properly show the terminating NUL character (`'\0'`). Use e.g. `printf(" %d = %c (%d)\n  ", j, name[j], (int)name[i]);` to see the character codes which would make the terminating NUL obvious.

Comment: @MOehm: `name[4] == '\n'` — see the printing.  `name[5] == '\0'` and thereafter the contents is junk.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, that's right. Missed the trailing new-line. But the edit period to my comment has ended, so I'll let my error stand ...

Answer (score 2):

When you entered characters `Hana` then the six elements of the array name got the following values

```
{ 'H', 'a', 'n', 'a', '\n', '\0' }
```

Note: `fgets` also places the new line character '\n' that corresponds to the pressed key Enter if the destination character array has enough space to store it.

All other elements of the array name did not get values.

To output the actual values of the array excluding the new line character and the terminating zero you could write

```
  for( j = 0; name[j] != '\n' && name[j] != '\0'; j++ ){
      printf(" %d = %c\n  ", j, name[j]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing out of the ordinary. The string "`Hana`" was stored in the `name` variable. The string is null-terminated, so 5 characters were written: '`H`', '`a`', '`n`', '`a`' and '`\0`'. The rest of the buffer was untouched.

You should not read outside the buffer boundaries, but within the buffer, everything after the terminating '`\0`' is untouched. Since you did not initialise the buffer, it may contain arbitrary data.

Comment: That is a fairly good description but you overlooked the newline which is retained by `fgets`.

Comment: Mostly, but `name[4] == '\n'` and `name[5] == '\0'` (which isn't written, of course).

Comment: The OP does not read outside the boundaries of the array. That's a confusion of yours. Reading of characters inside a `char` array is valid,  doesn't matter if it is content of the string or not. Also as mentioned before, it is wrong that 5 characters were written, in fact it were 6 with the read newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a string is not a `char` array. The proper string is everything up to the first null character, which terminates the proper string.

The array, here `name`, is the storage in which the string is stored. The string might not be as long as the array size, which is in your example the case, but the array needs to be capable of holding the string (including the terminating `\0`) at least.

The input `"hana"` by `fgets` occupies only the first 6 characters of `name` - `h`, `a`, `n`, `a`,`\n` and `\0`. Note that `fgets` also appends the newline character made by the press to Return to the proper string.

The character elements in `name` after the element with `\0` are not assigned with `\0`.

Everything what is printed after the `\0` is just garbage, because since `name` wasn´t either qualified with `extern` or `static`, the content isn´t initialized.

Note that `\n` and `\0` are non-printable
characters.

Answer (score -1):

You probably didn't initialize the array properly. Also, shouldn't you pass a pointer to the array you intend to use?

Comment: Where do you want the OP to "pass a pointer to the array"? All uses of `name` in function calls are correct, as far as I can see.

Comment: OP definitely did not initiliase the array *at all*.